# 'redirectToRoute' com query parameters - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony-2

Eu tenho uma rota `/curso/{slug}` que faz um redirect 301 para uma outra rota. Essa rota `/curso/{slug}` pode receber alguns parâmetros por query (exemplo: `/curso/{slug}?query=1234`), porém ao fazer o redirect para a outra rota utilizando `return $this->redirectToRoute('nova_rota', array('slug' => $slug)`, esses parâmetros de query se perdem. Como eu posso fazer para adicionar os parâmetros de query nesse redirect.

Bloco de código que faz o redirect para a outra rota:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/{slug}", name="course_show")
     */
    public function showAction(Request $request, $slug)
    {

        return $this->redirectToRoute('redirect_slug', array('slug' => $slug));
    }
```

Comment: Já tentou $this->redirectToRoute('redirect_slug', array('slug' => $slug, 'query' => 123))

Comment: Pode usa $request->request->all() pra pega os parametros e da um array_merge com o segundo parametro passado no redirectToRoute, assim ele vai pega dinamicamente todos os paramtros e envia no redirect tb.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.  Se você quiser, coloca como resposta da pergunta, pra eu marcar como resolvido...